# Método retorna corre solo 1 vez y retorna solo 1 valor

Tags: java, poo, netbeans, algoritmos

El problema es que el método que hice me retorna solo 1 valor, debo retornar los valores de un vector, pero con forma de String ahora hice el método (lo adjunto a continuación).

```
public static String toString(Estudiante estudiantes[]){
     String retorno = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < estudiantes.length; i++) {
        retorno = estudiantes[i].toString() + " ";
    } // For
    return retorno;
} // toString
```

Ese es mi método ahora, el método me retorna solo el valor del último indice ( se sobre escribe) , el resto no me los retorna y no entiendo por qué ya que el for es de 0 al lenght debería ser cambiante el valor de retorno.

Comment: Te devuelve solo uno porque eso es exactamente lo que estás poniendo que haga... `return` hace que el código detenga su ejecución y salga de la función / bucle en el que te encuentras. Si quieres el nombre de todos, no pongas el return ahí, simplemente vas concatenando los nombres en un string, con el formato que quieras, y luego devuelves ese string

Comment: actualicé mi pregunta

Comment: Se sobreescribe porque lo estás machacando cada vez... usa el asignador de concatenación `retorno += estudiantes[i].toString() + " ";`

Comment: cierto, creí que el + "" haría eso olvidé por completo el += gracias amigo

Comment: puedes ponerlo como respuesta para así dar la pregunta como resuelta?

Comment: Otro lo hizo ya, acéptalo y listo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agregarle el signo '+' dentro del bucle para ir concatenando tu contenido.

```
public static String toString(Estudiante estudiantes[]){
     String retorno = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < estudiantes.length; i++) {
        retorno += estudiantes[i].toString() + " ";
    } // For
    return retorno;
} // toString
```